# Having trouble save my output file as name based on cell from spreadsheet in google apps scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here's my code which was done mostly by a much talented coder then me:

```
function SaveSpreadsheetAs(){
  
var Sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var Peter=Sheet.getSheetByName("Peter");        
var Filename=Peter.getRange(2,2,1,1).getValue();
  //Folder to save pay periods on google drive
 var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("es3424kbjb4j32wbryujb3r"); 
              
 DriveApp.getFileById("093hnweuibf2873bfuiww").makeCopy(Filename,destFolder); 

 }
```

My question is why is (var Filename)'s output not the value of the B2 cell from the sheet name "Peter"? I know I am making a very basic level mistake as I am very new to this but what am I missing.  The code works if you change the (var Filename) with a text entry.  Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Working fine for me. I only changes the two id's... Sure it is in B2?

Comment: Okay now I see the deeper problem(I think).  I am trying to pull a date value from cell B2, I went in and changed B2 to a text value and it worked fine.  What do I need to do to pull a datevalue from the sheet? ie 4/21/2021

Comment: This is what I normally do:`const date = new Date(Sheet.getRange('A1').getValue());` This will work if it's a Date() or if it's a string that the Date constructor recognizes.  Generally, it just sames me a lot of trouble messing with spreadsheet dates.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help MetaMan.  I added your const and I am getting it to output a file named the current date in time.  I took out my "var Filename" and replaced it with your const.  What do I fill in the makecopy()'s first argument?  I tried Date and Date(date) but I just dont understand how to plug your const into the makeCopy() argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran it this way.  It runs fine.

```
function SaveSpreadsheetAs() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(gobj.globals.targetsh);
  const Filename = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(sh.getRange(2, 2).getValue()),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"MMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.testfolderid);
  const file=DriveApp.getFileById(gobj.globals.testsourceid).makeCopy(Filename, destFolder);
  Logger.log(file.getName());
}

Execution log
5:40:56 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:41:01 PM  Info    Apr-25-2021 17:40:41
5:41:01 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

gobj is a global object I use so that I don't have to remove my ids

Data Sheet:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
|  | 4/25/2021 17:40:41 |
|  |  |